# Does Maven find its central repository by default, if profile in settings.xml is empty?

Tags: maven, repository, profile

Suppose .m2/settings.xml does not contain a profile with any repositories. Will Maven try to resolve its central repository? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the default behaviour.